What does の延長に mean on this context?

「だって俺に告白してくれたことで色々悩んだと思う。でも、俺だって違う意味ではかなり悩んでいたのだ」


「もっと噛み砕いて言おう。オレの告白を拒否したのはオレのいう好きに、例えばキスのような性愛を含む行為が含まれているとわかっていたから、だよな」


「そして、キスの延長にあるものも見据えて、断った。……間違っているか？」」

Context: The character confessed to his crush and they finally became lovers. So he now asks for a kiss. He confessed once before, but the other character rejected him.


「そして、キスの延長にあるものも見据えて、断った。……間違っているか？」」


I understand the meaning seems to be akin to "You rejected me back then because you thought we would kiss", but why is の延長にあるも used?

キスの延長にあるもの refers to any actions that happen after kissing, like sexual intercourse for example.

The literal meaning of キスの延長にあるもの is "the thing that lies in the extended part of a kiss", where に is a location marker used with ある/いる. In other words, it refers to something that follows a kiss, or simply "a continuation of a kiss". For example, you can say 成功は努力の延長にある ("Success is what follows effort") and 趣味の延長にある仕事 ("a job as a continuation of a hobby").

そして、キスの延長にあるものも見据えて、断った。
And you foresaw what would come after the kiss, so you refused.

